# Will app.json post-deploy script run on production env as well as review apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using Heroku + Rails 5.1.
I just want my postdeploy script written in app.json to run only in Review Apps environment.

Comment: i guess they will indeed be run in production environments. Also interested in a possible solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this by setting a config var in my staging environment (the parent for my review apps) which tells my postdeploy that it is not in production. I added the cli webpack to app.json and inside my postdeploy I get the value of that config var and then conditionally execute code. In production, we set a different var.

You could also just check the $HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME inside the review app (you must have this env var defined in app.json for it to appear in review app), and if the parent app == staging (or whatever), don't execute whatever is in your post deploy

good luck, getting review apps to work right can be a huge pain